# Image file size differences between Imagemagick and GD library

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, imagick

I have been doing some tests and found out that Imagemagick creates larger file sized images compared to GD library.

I have tried using thumbnailImage method and also resizeImage method (with different filters) of Imagemagick for creating an image of max dimension 1024x680 jpeg with JPEG compression and quality 80 and at 72 pixels per inch resolution and am also using stripImage method to remove unneeded meta data. The file size created by Imagemagick is always in the range of 700KB to 800KB depending upon various filters. On the other hand GD library produces an image of size 1024x680 which is only 41KB in size.

Can anyone please explain the difference in file sizes. I opened up the 2 files in Photo shop and checked to see any differences but could not find any (DPI, color profile, 8 bit channel etc), but still cant explain the difference in file sizes.

Comment: Since the JPEG algorithm is standardized, the only difference remaining could be the type of storage: progressive/interlacing. If you are completely sure, all other settings (quality!) are equal.

Comment: Hi, I tried doing $image->setInterlaceScheme(Imagick::INTERLACE_JPEG);
and it reduced the size by 40KB or so still the image created is 711KB which seems to be pretty large compared to what GD library creates.

Answer (score 1):

```
$srgbPath = "pathTosrgbColorProfile";
$srgb = file_get_contents($srgbPath);
$image->profileImage('icc', $srgb);
$image->stripImage();
$image->setImageResolution(72,72);
$image->setImageUnits(1);
$image->setInterlaceScheme(Imagick::INTERLACE_JPEG);
$image->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
$image->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

$image->resizeImage($thumb_width,$thumb_nheight,imagick::FILTER_CATROM,1);
$image->writeImage($destination);
```

The size went down by 40KB giving an output of 711KB which is still pretty big. The Hi-res original file I am testing on is a jpeg of size 3008x2000 (4.2MB).

**Edit:**

I think I figured it out, the method `setCompression()` does it for the Object and not the image, instead I used `setImageCompression()` and `setImageCompressionQuality()` and now the size has reduced to 100KB.. All good now!

Comment: I think I figured it out, the method setCompression does it for the Object and not the image, instead I used setImageCompression and setImageCompressionQuality and it worked and now the size has reduced to 100KB..all good now.thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Quality settings of GD and ImageMagick aren't easily comparable, 80% in one does not mean the same as 80% in the other. I found the following note in an [article form Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/#quality-and-compression):

> It turns out that JPEG quality scales are not defined in a specification or standard, and they are not uniform across encoders. A quality of 60 in Photoshop might be the same as a quality of 40 in one program, quality B+ in another and quality fantastico in a third. In my tests, I found that Photoshop’s 60 is closest to -quality 82 in ImageMagick.

So you may pay more attention on quality when comparing the different result files. Maybe the colors differ or the gd image has more artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

The differnce seems rather large; when I did some tests a couple of years ago the file size of IM was about 5x the size of GD.
It would be interesting to see your actual code used.

I am at work at the moment but have a photo resized to 592 x 592 and the filesize is 50.3KB I know it is not the same size as yours but it was saved at quality 100

You can run this and see what IM says about the output files:
    convert image -verbose -identify

EDIT:

You must be doing something wrong I have just run a test and the results are below - For some reason the thumbnail size is the same as the resize size! Maybe a bug.

Original file size: 4700 x 3178 2.31MB

-resize dimensions = 1021 x 680 186kb

-thumbnail dimensions = 1021 x 680 186kb

GD dimensions = 1024 x 682 100kb

```
$original = 'IMG_4979_1.CR2';

// Convert to jpg as GD will not work with CR2 files
exec("convert $original image.jpg");

$image = "image.jpg";

exec("convert $image -resize 1024x680 output1.jpg");

exec("convert $image -thumbnail 1024x680 -strip output2.jpg");

// Set the path to the image to resize
$input_image = 'image.jpg';
// Get the size of the original image into an array
$size = getimagesize( $input_image );
// Set the new width of the image
$thumb_width = "1024";
// Calculate the height of the new image to keep the aspect ratio
$thumb_height = ( int )(( $thumb_width/$size[0] )*$size[1] );
// Create a new true color image in the memory
$thumbnail = ImageCreateTrueColor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );
// Create a new image from file 
$src_img = ImageCreateFromJPEG( $input_image );
// Create the resized image
ImageCopyResampled( $thumbnail, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $size[0], $size[1] );
// Save the image as resized.jpg
ImageJPEG( $thumbnail, "output3.jpg" );
// Clear the memory of the tempory image 
ImageDestroy( $thumbnail );
```